# How can I only find negative and positive numbers using re.findall?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list

I'm creating a program that reads 2 different files each filled with 10000 numbers, and calculates the mean and standard deviation of both of them. I have an issue when trying to create a list of all the numbers. I want to use re.findall to only find the negative and positive numbers and it to the list. But I can't seem to get it to work, it just returns an empty list no matter what I try. Here's my code so far:

```
import os
import math
import re

def mean(lst):
    total = 0
    nums = 0
    for i in lst:
        nums += 1
        total += i
    mean_num = total / nums
    mean_num = round(mean_num, 1)
    return mean_num

def std(lst):
    mean_num = mean(lst)
    total = 0
    nums = 0
    for i in lst:
        i -= mean_num
        i **= 2
        total += i
        nums += 1
    std_num = total / nums
    std_num = math.sqrt(std_num)
    return std_num

path1 = os.getcwd()
path1 += "/data/file_10000integers_A.txt"

path2 = os.getcwd()
path2 += "/data/file_10000integers_B.txt"

with open(path1, "r") as f:
    string1 = f.read()
    list1 = re.findall("^[-+]?\d*$", string1)
  

with open(path2, "r") as f:
    string2 = f.read()
    list2 = re.findall("^[-+]?\d*$", string2)

print(list1)
print(mean(list1), std(list1))
print(mean(list2), std(list2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the following pattern + `findall`

```
import re

content = 'this is a string with -123 numbers 456 789 - 1 some floats 1.23 -5.21 1.'
pattern = re.compile(r'(-?\d+\.?\d*)')
numbers = [float(match) for match in pattern.findall(content)]
print(numbers)
```

which outputs:

```
[-123.0, 456.0, 789.0, 1.0, 1.23, -5.21, 1.0]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much. Do you know what was wrong with my code?